# Swift: random depends from time on device

Tags: swift, random

I am novice programmer =)
Help me please with random generator.
I would like to seed the random number generator so that it won't be the same every time.

```
func randomteTxt() {

    var arr_person = [String]();
    arr_person.append("ГЕНЕРАЛ");
    arr_person.append("С КОЛБОЙ");
    arr_person.append("ШПИОН");
    arr_person.append("АРХИМЕД");
    arr_person.append("ШЕКСПИР");
    arr_person.append("С ФОНАРЕМ");
    arr_person.append("БАРОН");
    arr_person.append("ДИПЛОМАТ");

    let time = UInt32(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    srand(time)        

    greatperson.text = arr_person[Int( random()%(arr_person.count))];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSTimer` for that like add this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("randomteTxt"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And you can invalidate it when you don't need it.

Comment: Can you explain more about your need?

Comment: Sorry for my English. Can u read my question one more time, please.

Comment: Do you want to change `greatperson.text` every day?

Comment: I want when I run the app I have not had a similar sequence. Example: I launched the app, generated a great person . Then I close the app and start again generated the same great person.

Comment: Ok I understand your issue. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks you. I am waiting